# Elements of the Set of Rational Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

The set of rational numbers is defined as $\mathbb{Q} = \left\lbrace \frac{a}{b} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \land b \neq 0 \right\rbrace$.

This apparently means that $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ are distinct two elements of the set $\mathbb{Q}$. And similarly, every $\frac{0}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$ are also distinct elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. Is this right?

And if that is right, for a function $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ to be a bijection, there has to exists *distinct* $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ which satisfy $f(n) = \frac{0}{1}$ and $f(m) = \frac{0}{2}$, and of course $n \neq m$. Is this right as well?

Comment: The rational numbers are formed from equivalence classes of pairs where $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ if $ad - bc = 0$.  So $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ are the same element of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Hi, no it's not the case (although it's quite fair to be confused by the set notation above).  A more complete description: it is the set of pairs of integers (a,b) (excepting those where b=0) [quotiented by the equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Quotient_space) that (a,b) ~ (c,d) iff ad = bc.

Comment: The set of rational numbers is defined as $\displaystyle \mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{a}{b}| a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, b\neq 0, $ gcd $\{a,b\}=1\}$. So we cannot have $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ as two distinct elements in $\mathbb{Q}$, it is just $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Mathi: "is defined": _can be_ defined. This is not the only definition (indeed, it is not the usual one).

Comment: Hello everyone. I have never thought that I would receive a "no" for the first part of my question. I had been told by our instructor that *equivalent* elements $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ are indeed distinct, and merely just equivalent. If you insist that they aren't, then I have one more to ask: For $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ to be a bijection, should it be the case that $m = n$, given $f(m) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(n) = \frac{2}{4}$?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Yes, $\frac12=\frac24$ and therefore if $f$ is injective and $f(m)=\frac12$ and $f(n)=\frac24$ it follows that $n=m$. What may be confusing you is that the number $\frac24$ itself is defined as an equivalence class of pairs, which contains both $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$ (the latter two are _different_), and many more.

Comment: @ TonyK, then why don't you mention the ususal definition here? It may help the owner of this question.

Comment: @Mathi: The first two comments did that already.

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of the fact that the definition is not in terms of ordered pairs but rather in terms of fractions, all of the rules of fractions apply. In particular, for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $b\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, and $c\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ we have
$$\frac{ac}{bc}=\frac{a}{b}$$
and, as mentioned in the comments,
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$$
if and only if $ad-bc=0$.